# Sample project to know more on Java collections

Tags: java, collections

Can someone suggest a sample project[Any task/project/coding activity] where I can use Java collections extensively with core java? Intention is just to familiarize my self more with collections framework. I have basic to intermediate knowledge on the same. Asking here since I dont have the patience to do all exrecises from the Java tutorial.

Comment: I think one of the best ways is to implement a database or a phonebook with methods on them.

Comment: It's probably harder to find projects that you _can't_ use collections for...

Comment: @LouisWasserman: I know most of us will end up using Lists/ ArrayLists and even Maps. What I wanted to know was a task with enough scope to include most or all aspects of the collections framework. Thanks for the comment though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

very simple would be, write code to manage in memory student database. 
Provide option to 
- add/delete/modify students.
- compare students, 
- sort  student list sorted by name, by id.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think I will go with this unless I get something even better.

Answer (score 1):

Implement couple or more of classic algorithms on sorting arrays, reversing of lists, queue management, etc.